# iOS CoreLocation (null) crash

Tags: ios, core-location, exc-bad-access

I've been getting this error in my app through Crashlytics. I can't find where and how this crash occurs. Here is the log from Crashlytics:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  CoreLocation                   0x0000000183f62304 (null) + 60044
1  CoreLocation                   0x0000000183f230f0 (null) + 1436
2  CoreLocation                   0x0000000183f230f0 (null) + 1436
3  CoreLocation                   0x0000000183f2261c (null) + 1980
4  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183754c9c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
5  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183754940 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 884
6  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183752054 __CFRunLoopRun + 1520
7  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183680dc0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
```

and this is also stated:
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x6136383561626000

Anyone can point me to the right direction? Thanks

Comment: It says you are crashing in a timer callback. And that's _all_ it says.

Comment: Did you solved the issue ?

Comment: Did you solved the issue?

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, please let me know if you have resolved this issue or find out why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The timer needs to be invalidated when the app is becoming inactive. In the [applicationWillResignActive](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622950-applicationwillresignactive) method, invalidate the timer object. You can reset it back in the [applicationDidBecomeActive](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622956-applicationdidbecomeactive?language=objc) method. From the docs:

> You should use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and
>   throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to
>   pause the game. An application in the inactive state should do minimal
>   work while it waits to transition to either the active or background
>   state.

If you are building an app that needs to collect location in the background, ensure that you location updates background capabilities are utilised.

You can also try out the [HyperTrack](http://hypertrack.com) SDK for iOS which will set this up and more for you so that you can build your location feature and not worry about this grunt work. (Disclaimer: I work at HyperTrack.)