# Can iOS unload a system framework making it inaccessible to the app?

Tags: ios, core-location, exc-bad-access, crash-reports, segmentation-fault

I got this crash report from Crashlytics:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread SIGSEGV 0x000000000000002f

0  CoreLocation                   0x189f631d0 (null) + 78032
1  CoreLocation                   0x189f05960 (null) + 1688
2  CoreLocation                   0x189f04bf8 (null) + 2708
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1838c7dc0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1838c7ae4 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 864
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1838c72e4 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 248
6  CoreFoundation                 0x1838c4ecc __CFRunLoopRun + 1928
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1837e4c58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
8  GraphicsServices               0x185690f84 GSEventRunModal + 100
9  UIKit                          0x18cf3d5c4 UIApplicationMain + 236
10 MyApp                            0x102b6edd8 main (main.m:15)
11 libdyld.dylib                  0x18330456c start + 4
```

Which is similar to the one from this question - [iOS CoreLocation (null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899583/ios-corelocation-null-crash). I know from the logs that my app went several times successfully to background and then foreground. At some point main thread tries to access CoreLocation code which is (null).

Can iOS **unload a system framework** from the memory and not load it when app goes to foreground state?